# relation database issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I create relation between two tables (login_pre , privilege ) they are as follows:

privilege table:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  AccessLevel | login_id  | pre_id|
|----------------------------------|
|      1       |    1     |   1    |
|      2       |    1     |   2    | 
|      4       |    2     |   4    |
+----------------------------------+
```

and this is login_pre table:

```
    +----------------------------------+
    |  username| userpass | login_id   |
    |----------------------------------|
    |      a   |    123   |   1        |
    |      a   |    123   |   1        | 
    |      b   |   1234   |   2        |
    +----------------------------------+
```

**where admin who add accesslevel**

how can make php code that read   accesslevel= (1 or 2) of login_id =1

I write this code of two pages  but this read only accesslevel =2 of login_id =1 :

privilege page:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\database\agtdatabase\agt_site\connection\connect.php';



$query ="SELECT * FROM privilege " ;
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');    

             if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
        {  
        $query ="SELECT * FROM privilege AS privilege.login_id JOIN login_pre AS login_pre.login_id ON privilege.login_id=login_pre.login_id  WHERE login_id =1 "  ;

        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {


            // $_SESSION['sessionloginid']= $row['login_id'];// output 11
             $_SESSION['sessionaccess']= $row['AccessLevel'];//output 12 for user login id = 1

                }
        }

    ob_end_flush();
```

and protect page :

```
<?php

include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\database\agtdatabase\agt_site\login2\privilege.php');


function protect_page()
            {


    if($_SESSION['sessionloginid']== true && $_SESSION['sessionaccess']  )

    {
//header ('location:http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/agtSite/agt2.php');
 $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];   // output 1  
 echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] ;//output 2 for user loginid = 1 
exit();             

    }
}
protect_page();
?>
```

Comment: `and accesslevel in (1, 2) and login_id =1`

Answer (score 2):

How about a single query:

```
SELECT * FROM privilege AS p JOIN login_pre AS l 
ON p.login_id = l.login_id 
WHERE AccessLevel IN (1, 2) AND l.login_id = 1;
```

UPDATE

Not sure if you're aware, but this part is always overwriting the session data so you only get the last row:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $_SESSION['sessionloginid']= $row['login_id'];
    $_SESSION['sessionaccess']= $row['AccessLevel'];
}
```

Comment: It's just an alias for the privilege table (so I didn't have to write `privilege.login_id`, but `p.login_id` instead), it's not really important for solving your problem, but you should know it.

Comment: thank you but I have admin who add the accesslevel I think " WHERE AccessLevel IN (1, 2)" not proper in this case

Comment: So you want all accesslevels for a login_id?

Comment: Then just remove the accesslevel part from the WHERE clause, so it looks like this: `WHERE l.login_id = 1`

Comment: The query has to work. It will return all the rows where login_id is 1. Adjust your while loop because you're overwriting the id on every iteration.